# Wrapping code from C++ to use in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a C++ project which consists of some headers, cpps, some lib files and DLL files.

I want to wrap these files in order to use them on a C# project.

I wanted to make one DLL which will contain the all C++ project and then to wrap it with C# class so I would be able to work with it.

So my questions are (Working with Visual Studio 2010):

1. How do I make the final DLL file.

   a. I know how to link the lib files to the project, but how do i link the DLLs?

   b. What do I need to add to my headers in order that the functions declared in them (which are implemented in the lib files) will be imported to the DLL. (What is __declspec)?
2. After building the final DLL file, how do I create a C# project which use this DLL file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This is called (COM) InterOp. Fortunately one of the major design goals of the original .NET Framework was to facilitate easy interoperability between managed and unmanaged code. Broadly speaking there are three different kinds of interoperability that one may wish to achieve when dealing with managed code.

- Making calls into COM components from managed code
- Making calls into native DLLs from managed code. This known as platform invocation or colloquially, PInvoke. (This is what you want)
- Allowing COM components to call managed code by wrapping the managed code with a runtime callable wrapper (RCW). This can be used as a strategy for the piecemeal replacement of legacy code on a planned basis.

The process by which data is moved from the managed to unmanaged realm is known as marshalling. This is the name by which data and its associated types are serialised across some boundary or other. To support this process there are a collection of classes that exist under the System.Runtime.InterOp namespace.

Broadly speaking the process is essentially as follows:

- Determine function names (I use Dependency Walker)
- Determine function signatures (Look it up on MSDN if it's a MSFT one)
- Determine data types and structures required by code
- Write managed code to call into the native code that satisfies the criteria determined above
- Test the wrapper code that's after being written to ensure that it produces the expected results (this can often be the most tedious part)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for C++/CLI. With this hybrid you can write a dll that can contain any amount of normal C++ code and it can contain managed classes that can use .NET types (like System.String) for it's interface and internally handle your normal C++ types. That dll will be usable from C# like any other .NET dll. From the calling programs perspective will look as if you had written it in C#.

Normally answers should contain practical examples, but C++/CLI is a large field to cover, you could write books just describing your scenario. You can find a good tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes) and a good Overview [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh875047.aspx).

Comment: C++/CLI is an horrible way to wrap C++ calls, there are numerous pitfalls that require specialty knowledge of how "It Just Works" does things, it's insanely easy to find yourself with many many memory leaks and very slow code. I would **HIGHLY** recommend against using C++/CLI and instead recommend using direct COM interop using runtime callable wrappers, it's more explicit and you have more control over the lifetime of objects. If you just need to call C++ functions PInvoke is the way to go as it has no massive downsides like C++/CLI.

Comment: @Mgetz I agree with your assumption that you need a lot of .NET AND C++ knowledge to make that work correctly. However, if you have complex C++ code from the start needs more interfacing than just calling a few API functions, I found it easier than COM handling. But that's just an opinion, for other people, other ways may be better suited.

Comment: @nvoigt my experience, having done both routes is that C++/CLI never works just the way you expect it to. It's easy to get started with yes, but at the end of the day you never quite get it doing what you want and there are always memory issues. C++/CLI was designed for organizations that want to convert their code to be C++/CLR pure and need a temporary hold over. It was never intended for long term use. Runtime Callable Wrappers on the other hand WERE designed for long term use and have a very very predictable memory model and marshalling plan.

Comment: @mMgetz My experiences are the other way round: with C++/CLI there is little behind the scenes. You have to do it all yourself and if you do it right, it works like a charm. With automagic COM wrapping or Interop, if something fails, you are left with little to do or debug. It fails with a cryptic mesage and you are left guessing. But if your method works for you and my method works for me, I guess we are both happy. Whoever wants to do the same can try both ways and pick the one that suits him best.